# How to align a list of elements to bottom?

Tags: html, css, scroll, alignment

I'd like to align a list of elements inside of a container to bottom. By default it sticks to the top of the container.

Note that this list **needs to keep its scroll ability**. So I can't use flex. Flex makes elements resize and avoids scroll.

I can't think of an easy way to do this.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ez4paood/2/)

```css
#list {
  height: 200px;
}

.item {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin: 3px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="list">
  <div class="item">Item0</div>
  <div class="item">Item1</div>
  <div class="item">Item2</div>
  <div class="item">Item3</div>
  <div class="item">Item4</div>
  <div class="item">Item5</div>
  <div class="item">Item6</div>
  <div class="item">Item7</div>
  <div class="item">Item8</div>
  <div class="item">Item9</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way you can add a picture of what is the expected result?

Comment: Sure, just did :)

Comment: Why don't you just give  margin-top:100px; to #list id?

Comment: @NirjharVermani The number of items vary.

Answer (score 1):

There is a hack using `transform` scaling in the y-direction - see demo below:

```css
#list {
  height: 200px;
  border:1px solid green;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}
.item {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin: 3px 0;
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}
```

```html
<div id="list">
  <div class="item">Item0</div>
  <div class="item">Item1</div>
  <div class="item">Item2</div>
  <div class="item">Item3</div>
  <div class="item">Item4</div>
  <div class="item">Item5</div>
  <div class="item">Item6</div>
  <div class="item">Item7</div>
  <div class="item">Item8</div>
  <div class="item">Item9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Items and scroll are inverted.

Comment: @Elfayer that's why it is a *hack*... AFAIK your next best bet is using `absolute` *positioning*

Comment: I guess you're right, I thought I missed a CSS rule to stick the elements to bottom instead of top.

Comment: @Elfayer I tried with *absolute-relative* positioning too but could not get the scroll going correctly, hope you can find a better way :)

Comment: Actually absolute positioning doesn't make scrolls : https://jsfiddle.net/ez4paood/3/

Comment: @Elfayer check this out... I'm stuck at making the scrolls behave... https://jsfiddle.net/45sLeok6/

Answer (score 0):

```
#list {
  position: absolute; bottom: 0;
}
```

make sure to add `position: relative;` to the above element

https://jsfiddle.net/ege89t3h/